# Computation failed in `stat_bin()`: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed using Sturges' bining

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a histogram using Sturges' bining rule, yet I keep getting 2 errors, which probably have to do with the variable I am using, maybe because it has NA's?

Here is my process and the errors, what would you suggest?

```
k <- ggplot (world, aes (x=polstab))

wid <- ceiling ((max(world$polstab)- min (world$polstab))/ nclass.Sturges(world$polstab))

k + geom_histogram(col = "black", fill = "white", binwidth = wid)
```

Now, I get two error messages:

> Removed 9 rows containing non-finite values (stat_bin).

and:

> Computation failed in `stat_bin()`:
>   missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

The first one I understand, the second one is more problematic. What could I do to remove this error?

Comment: Hard to say without a reproducible example. What's `world`?

Comment: Hello, world is a .dta file  with lots of different variables, such as in this case political stability or corruption levels, hdi index etc.

Comment: Please share some data that will reproduce your issue. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The problem is that the data has 220 cases with lots of variables. I am quite new to RStudio and I am not very sure how much of the data is necessary to reproduce my issue.

Comment: If `polstab` does indeed have `NA` values, then `max(world$polstab)` and `min(world$polstab)` should each evaluate to `NA`, and as a result, `wid` would also evaluate to `NA`. You should do instead `wid <- ceiling ((max(world$polstab, na.rm = T)- min (world$polstab, na.rm = T))/ nclass.Sturges(world$polstab))`. Don't know if this would fix your problem without seeing the data. If there are many variables in your data, perhaps you can give us the output of `dput(world$polstab)`. This would give us the `polstab` variable in your `world` dataset.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!

Comment: @Jav, can you move your solution from a comment to an answer? Elsa if the answer is satisfactory, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If `polstab` does indeed have `NA` values, then `max(world$polstab)` and `min(world$polstab)` should each evaluate to `NA`, and as a result, `wid` would also evaluate to `NA`. You should do instead

```
wid <- ceiling ((max(world$polstab, na.rm = T)- min (world$polstab, na.rm = T))/ nclass.Sturges(world$polstab))
```